# Secure session cookie is not set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies, session-cookies

I'm trying to set the session cookie secure flag to true. I added the following to my environments/production.rb

```
ActionController::Base.session_options[:secure] = true
```

In the production mode I don't see the set-cookie header in the server response (I'm using the Tamper Data Firefox tool to view the traffic). I tried removing all cookies, manually setting the domain including the child domain(since domain is shared among many applications, the appache server forwards the requests to the right application and thus the request is always received by the application server as if it's coming from localhost).
I also tried to test it in development mode, I assume the server should at least set the cookie even if the request is over http but the browser won't send the cookie over http but again the server does not send the set-cookie header. The session works just fine if I don't set the secure flag. Am I missing something here?

Comment: If it is Rails 3.x it should be Rails.application.config.secret_token

Comment: Thank you for your comment but I'm in 2.3.8. I'm also trying to set the secure flag for the cookie not the session secret token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that in my version of actionpack, session cookies are only set over ssl.
Although by definition, the server can set a secure cookie when the request is over http but the browser will not send it with further requests. In my application I don't enforce ssl on the app level but on the appache level instead so the initial request made by rails is over http and the cookie is not set.