# Rails secure session and cookies are not working with a CDN

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, session, cookies, session-cookies

My setup looks like following: CloudFront CDN with https only and a EC2 Instnace orign http-only (all requests made to CloudFront are https, all requests made from CloudFront to ec2 are http)

If I set secure to **true** in my applications, **sessions and cookies are not saved anymore in any browser**. If I set it to **false** it works in most browsers, but **does not work in Safari**.

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_K_session', secure: true
```

My goal is to get session working for all the browsers. I don't really need the secure session setting.

Here is my simplified Terraform setup:

```
resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "main_rails_app" {
  origin {
    domain_name = "${aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment.main_rails_app.cname}"
    origin_id   = "${var.cf_main_rails_app_origin_id}"

    custom_origin_config {
      http_port              = "80"
      https_port             = "443"
      origin_protocol_policy = "http-only"
      origin_ssl_protocols   = ["TLSv1.1"]
    }
  }
  default_cache_behavior {
    allowed_methods  = ["DELETE", "GET", "HEAD", "OPTIONS", "PATCH", "POST", "PUT"]
    cached_methods   = ["GET", "HEAD", "OPTIONS"]
    target_origin_id = "${var.cf_main_rails_app_origin_id}"

    forwarded_values {
      query_string = true
      headers      = ["*"]

      cookies {
        forward = "all"
      }
    }

    min_ttl                = 0
    default_ttl            = 0
    max_ttl                = 0
    compress               = true
    viewer_protocol_policy = "redirect-to-https"
  }
  viewer_certificate {
    # cloudfront_default_certificate = true
    acm_certificate_arn      = "${data.aws_acm_certificate.some_domain.arn}"
    minimum_protocol_version = "TLSv1.1_2016"
    ssl_support_method       = "sni-only"
  }
  restrictions {
    geo_restriction {
      restriction_type = "none"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out Safari does send a Location header even if the form is hosted on the same domain and some other browsers don't. The location header value (cdn url) will not match with the application url (ec2 url) and the request will be marked as invalid in rails. I had `protect_from_forgery` instead of `protect_from_forgery with: :exception` and it took me quite a while to see this because i didn't receive any noticeable errors. The solution for me was to disable this setting:

```
Rails.application.config.action_controller.forgery_protection_origin_check = false
```

The default state of this setting was flipped in Rails 5.

Answer (score 1):

The cookie store is doing exactly what it should be doing, Rails received a cookie on an unencrypted session, CF to EC2 is unencrypted.

You have several options.

1. [Encrypt traffic between ec2 and cf if you want to set to secure: true. And force-ssl redirect as well.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SSL-on-an-instance.html)
2. Keep secure: false, since you're already trusting the connection between CF and EC2.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/security.html

[Secure session cookie is not set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13131036/secure-session-cookie-is-not-set?rq=1)

Comment: sorry for my misleading question, i would like to keep the secure: false, but it doesn't work in safari

Comment: What version of Safari and MacOS?

Comment: 10.13.5 macos and 11.1.1 safari

Comment: It looks like there are significant changes in High sierra and safari 11 to how it manages cookies. I think you'll have to work on toggle some preferences changes to allow the cookies to be used. https://blog.macsales.com/42331-learn-how-to-manage-cookies-in-safari-for-high-sierra

Comment: thanks, but disabling "prevent cross-site tracking using ITP" did not help